# Javascript call doesn't show up during runtime (asp.net)

Tags: javascript, asp.net, onblur, onfocus

I have an input element in my aspx page.

```
<input id="txtAllocAmt" type="text" class="txtAllocAmt" tabindex="2" size="10" name="Text1"
                       runat="server" disabled="disabled" onfocus="javascript:SetOldAllocAmt(this.id);"
                    onblur="ValidateAllocAmt(this.id);" />
```

The problem is that for some reason, javascript calls for both "onfocus" and "onblur" doesn't show up when the code is running as shown below.

```
<input onblur="" onfocus="" id="lvLienAllocations_ctrl0_ctl00_txtAllocAmt" class="txtAllocAmt"  tabIndex="2" name="lvLienAllocations$ctrl0$ctl00$txtAllocAmt" size="10" type="text">
```

For some reason "onblur" and "onfocus" are set to an empty string.

What is preventing asp.net code generator from generating those javascript calls?

Comment: Top is how it appears in ASPX markup and bottom is how it renders in browser?

Comment: Did you try put `onfocus="SetOldAllocAmt(this.id)"`  ?

Comment: @Yuriy Galanter: yes exactly.

Comment: @ Lucas_Santos: yes.  I just tried it and it didn't seem to work.

Comment: @Sung Can't recreate it. On a basic bare-bone ASPX page those attributes persist. Something else overwrites them in your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either remove runat=server, or add The events in code behind:

```
lvLienAllocations.Attributes.Add("onblur", "javascript:SetOldAllocAmt(" + lvLienAllocations.ClientID + ")";
```

Comment: I just tried it and it worked.  But I still can't figure out why this is happening.  As @Yuriy Galanter said, something could be overriding it.

Comment: not sure but if you want to dig further into it you could check what your clientidmode is set, either on the page directive, in the web.config under <page clientIdMode or on the control itself.